# No found anything when use searchbar in swift 3

Tags: swift, uisearchbar

I have a little problem. I can search in a array via searchbar. But when I search a city not in my array, doesn't change anything. I want to show error message this case. For example 'Not found any city'

My code is below:

```
var cities = [String]()
var citiesFiltered = [String]()
var searchBarActive:Bool = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    cities = ["Abu Dabi","Amman","Berlin","Catarman","Dortmund"]
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    if(searchBarActive){
        return citiesFiltered.count
    }
    return cities.count
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath)

    if(searchBarActive){
        cell.textLabel?.text = citiesFiltered[indexPath.row]
    }else{
        cell.textLabel?.text = cities[indexPath.row]
    }

    return cell
}

func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBarActive = true
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBarActive = false
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBarActive = false
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBarActive = false
}

func searchBarBookmarkButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBarActive = false
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    citiesFiltered = cities.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
        let txt : NSString = text as NSString
        let range = txt.range(of: searchText, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)

        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })

    if(citiesFiltered.count == 0){
        searchBarActive = false
    }else{
        searchBarActive = true
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//Try with this changes.

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    if(searchBarActive && citiesFiltered.count == 0){
        return 1
    }
    else if searchBarActive {
        return citiesFiltered.count
    }
    return cities.count
}

public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "myCell", for: indexPath)

    if(searchBarActive && citiesFiltered.count == 0){
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Not found any city"
    }
    else if searchBarActive {
        cell.textLabel?.text = citiesFiltered[indexPath.row]
    }
    else{
        cell.textLabel?.text = cities[indexPath.row]
    }

    return cell
}


func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    citiesFiltered = cities.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
        let txt : NSString = text as NSString
        let range = txt.range(of: searchText, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)

        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })


    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: else if searchBarActive {
        RETURN citiesFiltered.count
    } if you edit I will accept your answer @user3608500

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {

    citiesFiltered = cities.filter({ (text) -> Bool in
        let txt : NSString = text as NSString
        let range = txt.range(of: searchText, options: NSString.CompareOptions.caseInsensitive)

        return range.location != NSNotFound
    })

    if(citiesFiltered.count == 0){
        searchBarActive = false
    }else{
        searchBarActive = true
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

You are setting the bar as inactive, hence displaying the unfiltered list, when the filtered array is empty. 
By removing

```
if(citiesFiltered.count == 0){
        searchBarActive = false
    }else{
        searchBarActive = true
    }
```

You'll get an empty table when searching for something that is not on the list.

Comment: you are right. So, how can I show a special message when not fount anything?